# Send variable that contains an equation through ajax and return it to jquery fully computed

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

im trying to write a code where i will be able to send a variable that contains a mathematical equation through ajax and have it computed using php

the problem that i am getting is that once the php it returns the variable to jquery it doesnt compute it and still returns it as an equation

this is how i made it

jquery

```
$(".equals").click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var firstnum= $("#firstnum").val();
    var secnum= $("#secnum").val();
var operator= $('#operator').val();

var compute = firstnum+operator+secnum;
content = {compute:compute}
    $.ajax({
    url:'compute.php',
    type:'POST',
    data:content,
    success:function(response){
        console.log(response);
    }
    });     
});
```

php

```
<?php
    $compute =$_POST['compute'];

    echo $compute;

?>
```

for example the content of my variable compute is...

10+10

the php will still return it as is

what i want to happen is once it comes back from php it will return as

20

is there a way to make this happen?

thanks

Comment: You need to do this over PHP. What happens right now is exactly what i would expect with the current code.

Comment: What Scimonster probably means (although he didn't quite say it as such) is that your PHP code doesn't actually _do_ anything with your expression. That's simply because PHP recieves it as a string (without knowing anything about it) and then outputs that same string. PHP isn't told at any point that it has to do anything with the string... so it doesn....

Comment: Your current PHP code does exactly what is expected of it. It returns the input string unchanged. What you want is to add some code that actually does the calculation using the received formula and send the result back. Also, avoid blindly evaluating what you get as input from the client. A malicious user can wreck havoc on your site if that is allowed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want PHP to compute it, you should write something like this. Because when you send `10+10`, PHP sees it as a string.

Javascript:

```
$(".equals").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var firstnum= $("#firstnum").val();
    var secnum= $("#secnum").val();
    var operator= $('#operator').val();

    content = {first_number:firstnum,second_number:secnum,operator:operator}
    $.ajax({
        url:'compute.php',
        type:'POST',
        data:content,
        success:function(response){
            console.log(response);
        }
    });     
});
```

And at the PHP:

```
<?php
     $content = $_POST['content'];
     if( '+' == $content['operator'] ){
         echo $content['first_number'] + $content['second_number'];
     }
     else if( '-' == $content['operator']){
         //extraction 
     }
     // so on.. 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must have a calculator script on server side in PHP.
The mathematical expression must be parsed. You could use something like this

http://20xxproductions.com/code-samples?s=phpsc

for parsing more complex expressions.
If you have to process simpler ones you can specifiy an operator and give both numbers as extra POST variables.